# Variable Selection for GEE or other Longitudinal Methods When Dealing with Many Variables?

Tags: r, feature-selection, generalized-estimating-equations

I see the question of model selection for GEE come up and answers seem to usually involve QIC/MLIC for non-nested models, or LRT for nested. That's all fine, but when I have 50 predictors it's a bit tedious to write all 50-factorial model statements.

Some have floated stepwise selection using QIC/MLIC but my understanding is that stepwise tends to create a lot of problems and is generally considered outdated. What are better processes for screening initial variables that handle longitudinal data considerations well? This sample is with subjects being measured 1-4 times at varying intervals. I'm hoping for something I can implement in R, ideally.

Comment: Related https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/607074/56940

Answer (score 2):

I think "it's a bit tedious to write all 50 factorial model statements" should get some award for "biggest understatement on Crossvalidated"!

I would argue (as I often do) against any automatic method. The reasons for opposing this in ordinary multiple regression are, if anything, amplified in GEE. A good discussion of this is at [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection).

Instead, I suggest using your substantive knowledge and your intelligence to do this. 50 variables is a lot! In most situations, there are surely some near duplicates.  In the GEE context (or any longitudinal context) you might try removing ones that are missing a lot of data. (There are some areas where 50 variables is fairly common, but ... are you working in one of those?  You don't say what your subject is.)